# Gathering Performance Metrics (RAM, CPU, etc) AWS & Azure

Tags: amazon-web-services, performance, azure

We're developing a cross cloud plane performance metric harvester, to collect various performance metrics, but the top 3 being RAM usage, CPU Utilization and Disk Utilization. I know CloudWatch will provide us with CPU and Disk, but out of the box will not give us RAM. Generally speaking, what solutions do you/your organization use for collecting performance metrics from CloudResources? I've investigated New Relic and Chef (both are implemented in some level in our organization, but the coverage is shotty..), but I'm looking for something easy to deploy, maybe agentless... Any suggestions? Just putting feelers out there at this point.

Comment: This http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/mon-scripts.html

Comment: Yeah I saw that. Unfortunately it would be a political nightmare to get admins to apply this to all their resource. Plus this only covers AWS. We're also moving into the Azure space as well

Comment: You will have to install, configure or deploy something on the servers, you can't tell at the hypervisor level. Hopefully someone will have a low pain idea for you.

Comment: Have you checked out the LogAnalytics feature in Azure?  You can configure it to monitor storage accounts, as well as grab performance metrics from servers (CPU,ram,disk,etc)